# Define volume to host docker with jenkins helm chart by bitnami

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, minikube, bitnami

I'm running Jenkins helm chart - [by bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/jenkins/#installing-the-chart) on minikube local cluster.

I want to be able to build docker images in Jenkins pipelines, so I want to mount a volume to the host docker.
how can I use the chart parameters in order to mount a volume to the docker host?

currently i run this command to install the chard: helm install jenkins --set jenkinsUser=admin,jenkinsPassword=password,service.type=NodePort,service.port=8080 bitnami/jenkins

i tried to add to the parameters: extraVolumes=/Users/my-user/.docker:/home/jenkins/.docker:rw but i get this error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: could not find expected ':'

Comment: i can also use the official Jenkins helm chart, so if someone familiar how to do it with that chart please let me know

Comment: Check the Minikube documentation to mount a host directory to the virtual machine: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/

Answer (score 0):

I have [Installed Jenkins with Helm](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/#install-jenkins-with-helm-v3) in my environment and was able to mount a volume to the host docker using the below command,

```
$ chart=jenkinsci/jenkins

helm install <release-name> -n <namespace-name> -f <values.yaml> $chart --set extraVolumes=path/Sample_volumemount.yaml
```

Sample_volumemount.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pv
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  storageClassName: jenkins-pv
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: /data/jenkins-volume/
```

Instead of directories you can use the volume configuration files path.